# autoninja -C out\Default chrome gives me a error that i dont know how to fix windows10

Tags: python, windows, chromium, ninja

Does anyone know how to fix it? Windows 10.
I am trying to build my own chromium web browser for fast browsing and security.
I've been working days hours to fetch it and to be able to install Depot_Tools and during night time, i was building chromium and my PC turned off by a electricity cut during the process. can that have caused the error?
This is a very weird error and ill show the output:

```
"C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\ninja.exe" -C out\Default chrome -j 6
ninja: Entering directory `out\Default'
[190/43079] ACTION //chrome/common/extensions/api:generate...ndle_generator_schema(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x64)
FAILED: gen/chrome/common/extensions/api/generated_schemas.cc gen/chrome/common/extensions/api/generated_schemas.h
C:/Python39/python.exe ../../tools/json_schema_compiler/compiler.py --root=../../ --destdir=gen --namespace=extensions::api::%(namespace)s --bundle-name=Chrome --generator=cpp-bundle-schema --include-rules=extensions/common/api:extensions::api::%(namespace)s ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/accessibility_features.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/accessibility_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/activity_log_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/autofill_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/autotest_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/bookmark_manager_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/bookmarks.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/braille_display_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/chrome_web_view_internal.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/command_line_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/content_settings.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/context_menus_internal.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/context_menus.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/cookies.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/cryptotoken_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/dashboard_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/debugger.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/desktop_capture.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/developer_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/crash_report_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/downloads.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/downloads_internal.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/enterprise_hardware_platform.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/font_settings.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/gcm.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/history.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/i18n.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/identity.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/identity_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/image_writer_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/instance_id.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/language_settings_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/notifications.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/omnibox.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/page_capture.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/passwords_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/permissions.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/resources_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/safe_browsing_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/scripting.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/search.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/sessions.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/settings_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/signed_in_devices.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/system_indicator.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/system_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tab_capture.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tab_groups.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tabs.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/types.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/web_navigation.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webrtc_audio_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webrtc_desktop_capture_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webrtc_logging_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webstore_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/windows.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/processes.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/networking_cast_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/input_ime.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/enterprise_reporting_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/mdns.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/action.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/browser_action.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/browsing_data.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/extension.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/idltest.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/page_action.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/top_sites.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/app.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/commands.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/declarative_content.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/dom.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/privacy.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/proxy.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tts.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tts_engine.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/input_method_private.json
FAILED: Exception encountered while loading "../../chrome\common\extensions\api\privacy.json"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\compiler.py", line 209, in <module>
    result = GenerateSchema(opts.generator, file_paths, opts.root, opts.destdir,
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\compiler.py", line 55, in GenerateSchema
    api_def = SchemaLoader(root).LoadSchema(schema)
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\schema_loader.py", line 25, in LoadSchema
    api_defs = json_schema.Load(schema_path)
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\json_schema.py", line 44, in Load
    schemas = json_parse.Parse(handle.read())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 6863: character maps to <undefined>
[195/43079] ACTION //components/resources:about_credits(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x64)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

As suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407943/autoninja-c-out-default-chrome-gives-me-a-error-that-i-dont-know-how-to-fix-win#comment117403286_66407943) by [Asesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4781312/asesh) I tried to specify the the python of depot_tools, but it still doesn't work.  The error is:

```
"C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\ninja.exe" -C out\Default chrome -j 6
ninja: Entering directory `out\Default'
[73/42827] ACTION //chrome/common/extensions/api:generated...ndle_generator_schema(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x64)
FAILED: gen/chrome/common/extensions/api/generated_schemas.cc gen/chrome/common/extensions/api/generated_schemas.h
C:/Python39/python.exe ../../tools/json_schema_compiler/compiler.py --root=../../ --destdir=gen --namespace=extensions::api::%(namespace)s --bundle-name=Chrome --generator=cpp-bundle-schema --include-rules=extensions/common/api:extensions::api::%(namespace)s ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/accessibility_features.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/accessibility_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/activity_log_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/autofill_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/autotest_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/bookmark_manager_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/bookmarks.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/braille_display_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/chrome_web_view_internal.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/command_line_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/content_settings.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/context_menus_internal.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/context_menus.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/cookies.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/cryptotoken_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/dashboard_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/debugger.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/desktop_capture.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/developer_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/crash_report_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/downloads.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/downloads_internal.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/enterprise_hardware_platform.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/font_settings.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/gcm.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/history.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/i18n.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/identity.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/identity_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/image_writer_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/instance_id.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/language_settings_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/notifications.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/omnibox.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/page_capture.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/passwords_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/permissions.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/resources_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/safe_browsing_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/scripting.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/search.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/sessions.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/settings_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/signed_in_devices.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/system_indicator.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/system_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tab_capture.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tab_groups.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tabs.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/types.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/web_navigation.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webrtc_audio_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webrtc_desktop_capture_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webrtc_logging_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/webstore_private.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/windows.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/processes.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/networking_cast_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/input_ime.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/enterprise_reporting_private.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/mdns.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/action.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/browser_action.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/browsing_data.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/extension.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/idltest.idl ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/page_action.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/top_sites.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/app.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/commands.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/declarative_content.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/dom.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/privacy.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/proxy.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tts.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/tts_engine.json ../../chrome/common/extensions/api/input_method_private.json
FAILED: Exception encountered while loading "../../chrome\common\extensions\api\privacy.json"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\compiler.py", line 209, in <module>
    result = GenerateSchema(opts.generator, file_paths, opts.root, opts.destdir,
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\compiler.py", line 55, in GenerateSchema
    api_def = SchemaLoader(root).LoadSchema(schema)
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\schema_loader.py", line 25, in LoadSchema
    api_defs = json_schema.Load(schema_path)
  File "C:\Users\kyani\depot_tools\chromium\src\tools\json_schema_compiler\json_schema.py", line 44, in Load
    schemas = json_parse.Parse(handle.read())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 6863: character maps to <undefined>
[78/42827] ACTION //chrome/common/extensions/api:generated...ypes_schema_generator(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x64)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Looks like you have not followed the instructions properly. Depot tools is using pre-installed Python rather than using the version of Python it installs and uses.

Comment: how do i specify the python of depot_tools?

Comment: I think i found it and if it works now your answer is correct!

Comment: Still doesnt work at all sadly.

Comment: What error message do you see after doing so?

Comment: the same one, ill post it

Comment: Look at the error message properly, it's still using pre-installed Python rather than using Python from `depot_tools`